# How to Change Display with Jquery

Tags: jquery, tumblr

I'm just starting to learn jQuery but I'm not sure where I've messed up. I'm using the Tumblr API and trying to check `.likebuttontext`'s display. If it changes to none then make `.likedbuttontext` become a `display:table-cell`.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  if($('.likebuttontext').css('display') == 'none'){
    $('.likedbuttontext').css('display','table-cell');
  };
});
```

Comment: so when i understood you correctly you want to change the display to table-cell whenever it changes to none?

Comment: Indeed. I cant post the full css/html/jquery because of tumblr api im using

Comment: That's only going to trigger on load. You have to ask yourself what would cause the display of the like button to change and probably link your event handler to that event instead.

Comment: Thats where ive been a bit confused. Im using the tumblr like button to make the .likebuttontext remove. So if the button (.like_button) has the class .liked im changing the .likebuttontext to display:none. Could i check for like_button having the class .liked and use that?

My final objective is to have the button say Liked if the .like_button has the class .liked and say Like if it doesnt have .liked    

The class is delivered from Tumblr on the webpage load

Answer (score 2):

As a seperate of concerns you should not tamper with css via script.

Trying using classes like so:

```
$(function(){
  if($('.likebuttontext').hasClass("hidden")) 
      $('.likebuttontext').addClass("tableCell").removeClass("hidden")
})
```

Css:

```
.tableCell{
  display: table-cell;
}
```

EDIT:
After reading @Tyler  comments above here is another example:

```
$("button").on("click",function(){
 if($(this).hasClass(".liked_button"))
    $(this).addClass("hidden");
})
```

Comment: Very solid piece of advice. Keep the CSS where it belongs: in the stylesheet.